# What does "can only concatenate str (not "builtin_function_or_method") to str" mean?

Tags: python

When I start my code it shows me an error on 6th line -> "can only concatenate str (not "builtin_function_or_method") to str".

Could you help me to understand what is wrong? (I am a newby to coding)

```
firstName = input("Please, type in your name: ")

firstName = firstName.capitalize

print("Thank you " + firstName + " !")
```

Comment: `capitalize()`. Methods need `()` in order to be called

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9):

`firstName.capitalize` is a method.

You need to call it to get a result, which is a string:

```
firstName.capitalize()
```

Therefore:

```
firstName = firstName.capitalize()

print("Thank you " + firstName + " !")
```

Comment: OMG!! THANK YOU! I completely forgot about parentheses !!